# Bind a Class to Dropdownlist in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a class Site that has 3 properties (facility_id, facility_name and facility_code).  I am wondering if I can bind this to a dropdownlist so that when an option is selected I can access all 3 properties.  For purposes of testing I am just hard coding facility_code = "ASV".

```
List<Site> sites = new List<Site>();
string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
sites = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Site>>(responseString);

Site defaultSite = new Site { facility_id = -1, facility_name = "" };
sites.Insert(0, defaultSite);

sites = sites.Select(x => new Site { facility_id = x.facility_id, facility_name = x.facility_name, facility_code = "ASV" }).ToList();

dropDownSites.DataValueField = "facility_id";
dropDownSites.DataTextField = "facility_name";
dropDownSites.DataSource = sites;
dropDownSites.DataBind();
```

Below is where I don't know how to access the properties of each Site.  I have an error saying 'Cannot convert type ListItem to Site...)

```
string facilityCode = (dropDownSites.SelectedItem as Site).facility_code.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot bind multiple properties. You have to find the correct item again after PostBack with the SelectedValue of `facility_id` in the `sites` list.

But if you really want you can put all properties in a single string, put it as the `DataValueField` and then split the string again on PostBack. So create an extra property that returns all properties in a single string. Although this works it is not the cleanest of solutions.

```
public class Site
{
    public int facility_id { get; set; }
    public string facility_name { get; set; }
    public string facility_code { get; set; }

    public string facility_DataValueField
    {
        get
        {
            return facility_id + ";" + facility_name + ";" + facility_code;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use that property as the DataValueField

```
dropDownSites.DataValueField = "facility_DataValueField";
```

Then on PostBack you can split the DataValueField to get the values again.

```
string [] properties = dropDownSites.SelectedValue.Split(';');
```